# Can I control the profile image shown in the Facebook activity feed

Tags: facebook, profile

I am creating a Facebook activity feed of [my page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/NanoChannels-Talking-Nano/196310443734355) for my site, and it of course shows the profile picture. The problem is that the profile picture is very big, and when it shows up in the activity feed, it's cropped in not such a nice way.

Is there a way for me to tell the feed what part of the profile picture to take?

Answer (score 1):

From your page go to **Manage** » **Edit Page** » **Profile Picture** » **Edit Thumbnail**.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is way to do this other than to play with aspect ratios and optimize.